# Is there an easy way to create game related functions like in unity with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a game engine in pygame mainly for the experience.

I want something that looks like this.

```
class class_name:

    def start() # Run on start
        pass

    def update(): # Update every frame
        pass
```

Comment: You can type this into your text editor and then you have something that looks like this. I'm not sure what you are having difficulty with.

Comment: I want a separate file to handle the events like start and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something such as

```py
import pygame


HEIGHT: int = 1280
WIDTH: int = 720
MAX_FPS: int = 60

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((HEIGHT, WIDTH))
clock = pygame.time.clock()


class Game:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Setup the game and load the assets."""
        self.is_running = True

    def run(self) -> None:
        """the core game loop."""
        while self.is_running:
            self.update()

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(MAX_FPS)

    def update() -> None:
        """handle the game update every frames."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.is_running = False

def main() -> None:
    game = Game()
    game.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will give you a blank windows to start with.